# AWS credentials required for Common Crawl S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, common-crawl, aws-credentials

I'm trying to get at the Common Crawl news S3 bucket, but I keep getting a "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" message. Any suggestions for how to get around this? As far as I was aware Common Crawl doesn't even require credentials?

Answer (score 2):

From [News Dataset Available – Common Crawl](https://commoncrawl.org/2016/10/news-dataset-available/):

> You can access the data even without a AWS account by adding the command-line option `--no-sign-request`.

I tested this by launching a new Amazon EC2 instance (without an IAM role) and issuing the command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/
```

It gave me the error: `Unable to locate credentials`

I then ran it with the additional parameter:

```
aws s3 ls s3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-NEWS/ --no-sign-request
```

It **successfully listed** the directories.

Comment: Tried the command with the additional parameter and received this message: n error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Comment: According to the [access documentation](https://commoncrawl.org/get-started), `--no-sign-request` should work. However, I can verify that it is not currently working. I am able to access the data by using my personal AWS credentials and omitting `--no-sign-request`, but it is not currently working for 'anonymous' access. I have sent a message to Common Crawl on their website to let them know.